# How to solve four variables coupled nonlinear equations?

Tags: nonlinear

```
Solve[x1*(1-x1^2-y1^2)-w*y1+e*(0.5*Q*(x1+x2)-x1)+h==0&y1*(1-x1^2-y1^2)+w*x1==0&x2*(1-x2^2-y2^2)-w*y2+e*(0.5*Q*(x1+x2)-x2)==0&y2*(1-x2^2-y2^2)+w*x2==0,{x1,y1,x2,y2}]
```

I use this code in Mathematica to solve this coupled nonlinear set of equations, and want to find (x1,y1,x2,y2) analytically. But it can not return any value, the code is running ...... for a long time . I tried several times, but the Mathematica can not give solution. I also use `Reudce` command , but still no output comes.

Can anyone have the solution for this problem in Mathematica ?

Comment: While it won't eliminate your problem, [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) is `&&`  rather than `&`

Comment: Are there any known constraints on the parameters `{e, h, Q, w}` and/or the variables `{x1, y1, x2, y2}`? Real? Positive?

Comment: Why do you need an analytical solution what will take a dozen pages ?.It not better to solve numerically.

Comment: No, there is no known parameters or variables . I want to find a purely analytical solution for this system @BobHanlon

Comment: May be the solution is lengthy , but I want to know is it possible to solve this equations with Mathematica or NOT ? @MariuszIwaniuk